# Rails + Multiple DataTables + UI nested accordion

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, twitter-bootstrap, datatables, jquery-ui-accordion

I'm using multiple similar dataTables within a nested UI accordion. While I've had no problem initializing multiple dataTables using the class-level selector, I'm having a problem getting the header and footer of any given table to align correctly.

I assume this is the same problem as a dataTable in a tab: the table (or header) needs to be redrawn once the accordion pane is displayed.

With initialization of a single table, or id-based initialization, I've had no problem using fnDraw or fnAdjustColumnSizing in a function to redraw a table on display. However, using mass-initialization, this approach doesn't work, because the specific displayed table can't be easily targeted.

I've tried to find a way of targeting only the currently displayed table for redraw, but haven't been successful.

Has anyone else dealt with this issue successfully? Thanks for any ideas....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sure this is super-hacky, but the only way I could set it up so I could create a dynamic, multi-level accordion with a dataTable nested within each, was to actually nest the dataTable initialization within the accordion activation (at the level of the table), then mark the table div as initialized so it could be re-opened. Here's my js code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(function() {   
        $('.accordion.second-level').bind('accordionactivate', function (event, ui) {

              if (ui.newPanel.length) {
                 thisPanel = ('#'+ ui.newPanel.attr('id'));
                 if ($(thisPanel).hasClass('not_activated')) {
                     $(thisPanel + ' .dataTables_types').dataTable({
                            "bAutoWidth": false,
                            "bPaginate": false,
                            "bScrollCollapse": true,
                            "sScrollY": "295px",
                            "aaSorting": [[ 1, "desc" ]],
                            "sDom": "<'row'<'span10'f>>t<'row'<'span10'i>>",
                             "aoColumns": [
                                            { "bSortable": false },
                                            null,
                                            null,
                                            { "iDataSort": 4 },
                                            {'bVisible': false},
                                            {'bVisible': false},
                                            null
                                          ],
                            "fnFooterCallback": function ( nRow, aaData, iStart, iEnd, aiDisplay ) {
                                           /* Calculate the total transactions on this page */
                                          var total = 0;
                                           for ( var i=iStart ; i<iEnd ; i++ )
                                          {
                                            total += aaData[ aiDisplay[i] ][5]* 1;
                                           }
                                           var nCells = nRow.getElementsByTagName('th');
                                           nCells[1].innerHTML = total;
                                           $(nCells[1]).formatCurrency({negativeFormat:'%s-%n'});
                            }
                    });
                   $(thisPanel).removeClass('not_activated');
                 }
                } 
        }); 
    });
});
```

I'd still love to know if there's a better/more efficient way to do this, but this does work.